# Dart Firebase off() method

Tags: angular, dart

I am using AngularDart. I want to change the reference I am listening to by removing/adding the active listeners.

From the link and "Detach listeners" documentation below it looks like I need the off() method to remove active listeners so that a new listener can be added.

**Question: How to use the off() method in Dart.**

[document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Detach listeners:

Callbacks are removed by calling the off() method on your Firebase database reference.
You can remove a single listener by passing it as a parameter to off(). Calling off() on the location with no arguments removes all listeners at that location.
Calling off() on a parent listener does not automatically remove listeners registered on its child nodes; off() must also be called on any child listeners to remove the callback.

Answer (score 0):

In Dart you use `listen()` to subsribe to notifications.
`listen()` returns a [StreamSubscription](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-async/StreamSubscription-class.html#constructors) that you can use to unsubscribe by calling its `cancel()` method.

Comment: Calling cancel() did not work for me; the app behaved as if the callback was still registered after calling cancel().  Instead I learned more about firebase.database.Query.  The app uses an orderByChild and equalTo Query to get the right data instead of adding/removing listeners.  This works and seems to be the right way to go.